# Equivalent of ::class for functions

Tags: php, function

Is there a way to get the fully qualified name of a function, in a similar way to `::class` for interfaces and classes?

I'm doing some functional-style programming, and need to be able to pass callables around. I'd like to use 'proper' functions, but I don't want to hard-code namespaces in strings everywhere. As far as I can see, the only alternative is to use a utility class with static methods.

For example, suppose you have a function `bind` that binds some arguments of a function. If I use proper functions, I have to do this:

```
<?php
// File1.php
namespace some\quite\long\nspace;
function add($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }

// File2.php
$f = bind('some\\quite\\long\\nspace\\add', 1);
```

With static methods, this becomes:

```
<?php
// File1.php
namespace some\quite\long;
final class nspace {
    public static function add($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }
}

// File2.php
use some\quite\long\nspace as n;
$f = bind([n::class, 'add'], 1);
```

Not only is this shorter, it is also better for refactoring (although not perfect since it still has a string method name).

In an ideal world, I would like to do something like this:

```
<?php
// File1.php
namespace some\quite\long\nspace;
function add($a, $b) { return $a + $b; }

// File2.php 
use function some\quite\long\nspace\add;
$f = bind(add::name, 1);
```

Is anything like this possible? If not, I think this is enough to persuade me to use static methods on final classes instead of 'proper' functions.

Comment: I'd honestly just recommend using a class wrapper for your code. Just group your global functions based on utility type and create classes with static methods. Otherwise, look into `__NAMESPACE__` constant, maybe that'll help you.

Comment: `__NAMESPACE__` is only useful if you're in the same namespace as the callable you want to pass, which isn't always the case. Static methods it is then. Seems like first class functions is another thing that PHP half-does...